# Disabling recentf mode?

Tags: init-file, spacemacs, debugging, recentf

I try to disable this via

```
(recentf-mode -1)
(setq recentf-mode nil) ;; mysteriously switches to t after some time
```

but it keeps automatically turning on after some time and is causing problems for me (see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacemacs/comments/70bm2b/getting_rid_of_constant_recentf_changed_on_disk/)).

Comment: How about grepping your config for `recentf-mode` to see where else it is being set?  Also, consider grepping your installed libraries for the same thing.  For example, a certain feature of `ido-mode` relies upon `recentf-mode` ....

Comment: What @lawlist said. Or bisect your init file to find the culprit. In general, if you have a problem and you don't have it when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file), they check your init file to see how/where you are shooting yourself in the foot.